# How to force container elements to contain horizontal content?

Tags: html, css

Here's an example of what I'm trying to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/U2YkF/3/

I need `#container` to expand to fit `#right` when `#right` extends off the right hand side of the screen. Clearfix doesn't seem to be the answer as I've tried that: it only affects the vertical content.

Comment: I can not understand your question. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Mohsen: If you look at the JSFiddle that I linked and shrink the display area so that the green area stretches off screen then the red outline will not surround it. I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#container {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: sorry... overflow:auto; will make it work (but with scrollbars)

Comment: `display: inline-block` does work, but note that it won't work in IE7 (if that matters).

Comment: @thirtydot: does this work in IE7 if you set it to `block` in a conditional stylesheet?

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: `display: block` is the default for `div`s, so setting that in any browser won't make a difference. You can usually make `display: inline-block` work in IE7 with `display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1`, but in this instance, that doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/mGzbk/ (`*property` means "only for IE7 and lower") (you can test this yourself if you hit F12 in IE to bring up the Developer Tools and switch to IE7 mode)

Comment: +1 for solving my issue in practicality, this works in IE7 in my environment for one reason or another. Hesitant to accept as it doesn't work in IE7 for the simple JSFiddle case though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what you needed with a few lines of JQuery:

```
x1=$("#right").width();
x2=$("#left").width();

$("#container").width(x1+x2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to add `float: left` to `#container`.

http://jsfiddle.net/U2YkF/6/